Problems with Kubuntu install on 2017 Intel iMac
This is my first foray into Linux. A couple of months ago, I installed Kubuntu on a 2017 Intel chip iMac that has all original equipment (1TB "fusion drive" - which may be part of the issue?) plus added RAM (32GB RAM total). Install went smoothly. I did not install it as a parallel operating system. I just wanted to replace the Mac OS because it cannot be updated any longer, and it really does not run well for anything. Kubuntu was my hope for a way to keep using the gorgeous 27" monitor.
Kubuntu has since been running fine, but I realized yesterday I must not have partitioned the drive correctly (or the fusion drive prevented it?), because I have only 30GB of disk space showing in Dolphin file directory.
I thought, Oh well, I'll just reinstall Kubuntu and try to do the partition correctly this time, but when I boot up with an install (on a USB), the install does not run properly. Instead I end up dumped into initramfs. I tried fsck, but it returned a "fsck not found" result.
Any suggestions on how I might fix this mess would be very much appreciated. I am bright but absolutely not a computer tech, so while I am very good at following step-by-step instructions, I don't know enough to think generally about these things.
Specs:
   3.5GHz quad core Intel Core i5
   Radeon Pro 570 with 4GB of VRAM
   SDXC card slot
   Four USB 3 ports (compatible with USB 2)
   Two Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for USB 3.1 Gen 2 (up to 10 Gbps)
   10/100/1000BASE-T Gigabit Ethernet (RJ-45 connector)
   802.11ac WiFi
   Bluetooth 4.2

Thank you, guiverc. I used the Kubuntu installer for 24.04.1 LTS, which I downloaded (64-bit download) to my MacBook Air (M2 2022). I then used BalenaEtcher on my MacBook to create a bootable USB-C flash drive to install Kubuntu on the old iMac.
